# Erro Repositório Git / Github

Tags: git, github

Devs,

Estou iniciando no uso do GIT e GITHUB e infelizmente escolhi um repositório local diferente do que eu gostaria, tentei excluir isto e acabei criando mais repositórios, inclusive com branches diferentes.

Existe alguma maneira de começar isso do zero? Uso VSCode e sou iniciante em programação Python...

Já pesquisei em encontrei muitos comandos, mas nada deu certo...

Obrigado

Comment: recomendo apagar todas as pastas ocultas com as informações do git e recomeçar um novo repositório do zero. No próprio explorador de arquivos, dentro da pasta do repositório ao exibir os arquivos ocultos, verá uma pasta com o nome .git, onde está todas as informações do repositório que criou. Ao apagar a pasta do .git, o caminho não será mais um repositório versionado, aí poderá começar tudo novamente, digitando o comando `git init` no terminal.

Comment: Vou fazer isso. E fazendo isso, já zera também o GitHub?

Comment: Aparentemente não. Como o GitHub é uma ferramenta de versionamento de código, quando você der `git remote add origin --link do repositorio--`, a versão atual do seu projeto será atualizada com as modificações que ocorreram até o momento.

Comment: E tem alguma maneira de tirar do github algum repositório que eu não queira que esteja lá?

Comment: Sim, é só ir nas configurações do repositório e nas penúltimas opções da primeira guia, vai estar lá a opção de deletar o repositório. Acho que antes de excluí-lo, precisa digitar a senha ou a credencial do repositório que é definida pelo sistema e é o padrão das configurações do GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

O git é interessante por que ele é baseado em pastas e arquivos do sistema operacional, por isso existe uma pasta oculta ".git", na pasta que você criou o repositório com o comando "git init".

Portanto você pode mover esse repositório a qualquer momento e para qualquer lugar do seu HD.

Outro ponto importante é que o seu repositório local não é conectado com o remoto, o git é um [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control), controle de versão distribuído, mas você consegue controlar um repositório remoto, como deletar uma branch, por exemplo, entre outras coisas.